# How to Open Finder in Mac Catalyst 13.0+ swift

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst

He there, 
I'm trying to open (Launch) a Finder in Mac Catalyst 13.0+.
and the '[NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace)' is unavailable in Mac Catalyst

My code:

```
func openFinder(url: URL?){
    guard let url = url else { return }
    NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([url])
}
```

Error:

> 'NSWorkspace' is unavailable in Mac Catalyst

Do you have any idea how I can do it in Mac Catalyst?

Comment: https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit

Answer (score 8):

`NSWorkspace` is actually available but not visible to the app. You can call the method dynamically using message sending techniques. One way to do that is by using the [Dynamic](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) library:

```swift
Dynamic.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.activateFileViewerSelectingURLs([url])
```